# What variable do i add when i am calling a method array?

Tags: java

So basically i am trying to call this method.

```
    public void freq(int[] arr)
```

In my main class

```
    Freqq start = new Freqq();
    start.freq(?);
```

what should i add as a variable here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: google pass an array to a method parameter. You will find plenty of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass integer array like below:

```
 start.freq(new int[]{1,3,5,6});
```

or

```
 int[] a = new int[]{3,4,6,7,6};
 start.freq(a);
```